# My break statement it's not breaking the while statementin my code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a program where the user can enter a positive numbers, but if the user enters a negativ number the the program should break and print out the smallest, biggest, sum and average of these numbers. The problem is, the code breaks when the user enter 0 and don't run the code after while function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int integer, small, bigg, sum, i;
float average;

while (1) {

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &integer);
    i++;
    integer = bigg = small;

    if (integer > bigg) {
        bigg = integer;
    }

    if (integer < small) {
        small = integer;
    }

    sum = integer + sum;
    average = sum / i;

    if (integer < 1) {
        break;
    }
}

printf("The smallest number is: %d", small);
printf("The biggest number is: %d", bigg);
printf("\nThe sum of the number: %d", sum);
printf("The average value is: %f", average);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &integer); integer = bigg = small;` You read the  user input into `integer` and then immediately throw it away by overwriting with `bigg`. Makes no sense and is one of multiple problems.

Comment: Suggest you learn to debug effectively. Then you will be able to find such basic errors yourself. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line, examining the variable values as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: that because divide by using it's undefined so you need to check if value <= 1 + debugging you code for seeing what's happen step by step  :)

Comment: You simply don't initialize variables properly.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are not initialized by default. Initially their value is indeterminate. There are some other problems (see comments for explanations).

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>     // needed for INT_MAX and INT_MIN constants

int main(void) {
  int integer;
  int small = INT_MAX;   // initialize to biggest possible number
  int bigg = INT_MIN;    // initialize to smallest possible number
  int sum = 0;           // initialize to 0
  int i = 0;             // initialize to 0
  float average;

  while (1) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &integer);
    i++;

    //// integer = bigg = small;    // this statement is pointless, it just
                                    // overwrites integer inputted 2 lines above

    if (integer > bigg) {
      bigg = integer;
    }

    if (integer < small) {
      small = integer;
    }

    sum = integer + sum;
    average = (float)sum / i;    // (float)sum : converts to float prior to division
                                 // because otherwise we'd have an integer division
    if (integer < 1) {
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("The smallest number is: %d\n", small);  // added \n so output is readable
  printf("The biggest number is: %d\n  ", bigg);
  printf("\nThe sum of the number: %d\n", sum);
  printf("The average value is: %f\n", average);

  return 0;
}
```

There is still a small problem left. I let you find out yourself.